# Unable to create a new session key. It is likely that the cache is unavailable

Tags: django, redis, bitnami

I am running bitnami/redis helm chart in my kubernetes cluster. my django app is using it as a session cache.

```
CACHES = {
    'default':
        {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://redis-service:6379/0",
        "OPTIONS": 
            {
                "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient"
            }
    }
}
```

heres how my session_engine variable looks like

```
SESSION_ENGINE="django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
```

This setup worked just fine when I was running redis as a single replica deployment. when I switched to bitnamis helm chart (with sentinel) I started getting this error intermittently when I try to login to admin page

> Unable to create a new session key. It is likely that the cache is
> unavailable.

If I switch over to single pod Redis deployment it works fine. but using a bitnami helm chart seems to be causing this issue.

I can confirm I can reach the Redis cluster from my Django pod. what's more confusing is it's causing intermittently.

any help will be much appreciated.

UPDATE 1.

after checking the logs of redis I get this

```
1601409529.593320 [0 10.2.1.77:58836] "EXISTS" ":1:django.contrib.sessions.cachendvrotljwn4502p278mbmvxy1l5xgkqk"
1601409529.594428 [0 10.2.1.77:58836] "EXISTS" ":1:django.contrib.sessions.cachezw19k1uqzb164h1n9x8b8dcjywrwltva"
1601409529.595374 [0 10.2.1.77:58836] "EXISTS" ":1:django.contrib.sessions.cachejf4y14zd7ll9rjtc8fh6ecicu3mqsbpn"
1601409529.596342 [0 10.2.1.77:58836] "EXISTS" ":1:django.contrib.sessions.cacheaacgflnnjvwjkb4kjahsr8qir3qxgua1"
1601409529.597401 [0 10.2.1.77:58836] "EXISTS" ":1:django.contrib.sessions.cachelhx6l6hgikkhb958iynvdmjyz4tqkwig"
1601409529.598442 [0 10.2.1.77:58836] "EXISTS" ":1:django.contrib.sessions.cachewaemv1rhy6j1lel5j87vt30e3c5saanq"
1601409529.599485 [0 10.2.1.77:58836] "EXISTS" ":1:django.contrib.sessions.cachegs5rmaz3sc8scevoczbcozd6fh4svukl"
1601409529.600538 [0 10.2.1.77:58836] "EXISTS" ":1:django.contrib.sessions.cache19k1kr63ql4odwwqc9e0l1uv7oj4ck0j"
1601409529.601610 [0 10.2.1.77:58836] "EXISTS" ":1:django.contrib.sessions.cachemdci7awb7z5wmdcim093tfehu2e60ru6"
1601409529.602664 [0 10.2.1.77:58836] "EXISTS" ":1:django.contrib.sessions.cacheeubmkiqvc0gnn273er86c2qoscauqzqa"
```

looks like its comming from this https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/backends/cache.py#L42

so django tries to insert key into cache and to avoid collision it tries 10000 times before throwing an exception.

I can see there are no keys in the redis.

on a successful login logs look like this

```
1601410010.012538 [0 127.0.0.1:53662] "ping"
1601410010.308631 [0 10.2.1.74:6379] "SET" ":1:django.contrib.sessions.cachee7f697vcuv1fyxfyvgw6uexyv2w58o1a" "\x80\x05}\x94." "PX" "1209600000" "NX"
1601410010.323639 [0 10.2.1.74:6379] "SET" ":1:django.contrib.sessions.cachee7f697vcuv1fyxfyvgw6uexyv2w58o1a" "\x80\x05\x95\xb0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\x94(\x8c\r_auth_user_id\x94\x8c\x0224\x94\x8c\x12_auth_user_backend\x94\x8c)django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend\x94\x8c\x0f_auth_user_hash\x94\x8c@dccdd9eb53e5ebfcd0f544de6aefa932892729837c6d16257be00d5715204eda\x94u." "PX" "1209600000"
```

Comment: You should probably look into the Bitnami deployment's logs to figure out what's happening.

Comment: thats great. I am updating the question @AKX